# Azure functions integration testing locally

Tags: azure, rest, process, integration-testing, restsharp

I am trying to run integration tests on an azure functions project locally. My method is to start the azure server programatically using a process. This does not work for some reason.

This is how i setup the process:

```
private Process process;
private RestClient client;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp()
{
    const string dotnetExePath = @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe";
    const string functionHostPath = @"C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.24.0\cli\func.dll";
    const string functionAppFolder = @"C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\ShyftApi\ShyftApi\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0";

    process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = dotnetExePath,
            Arguments = $"\"{functionHostPath}\" start -p {7001}",
            WorkingDirectory =  functionAppFolder
        }
    };

    bool success = process.Start();
    Assert.AreEqual(true, success);
    client = new RestClient($"http://localhost:{7001}/api");
    Thread.Sleep(8000);
}
```

`OneTimeSetup` succeeds without an error so i assume that the process started correctly (but i see no azure shell, wierd?)

I run a simple http call (using restsharp):

```
[Test]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/test", Method.POST);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Assert.AreEqual(200, response.StatusCode);
}
```

This is the azure function that i am trying to test:

```
[FunctionName("test")]
public static IActionResult Test([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
    return new OkObjectResult("ok");
}
```

The test fails because `response.StatusCode` is 0 so i assume that the server is not up.

I followed the format used in https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/11/08/integration-testing-precompiled-v2-azure-functions/ for the arguments to the process. I have manually checked that the paths are correct (But the process starts sucessfully so i dont think the paths are the issue?).

The endpoint i am trying to hit is `http://localhost:7071/api/test` and when running the azure server regurarly (F5) and accessing it through my browser i get a 200 ok.

What do you think could be the issue? The starting arguments to the process or am i just using the wrong url?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now:

```
private Process process;
private RestClient client;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp()
{
    //Path to azure cli:
    const string functionHostPath = @"C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.24.0\cli\func.exe"; 
    //Path to project build location:
    const string functionAppFolder = @"C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\ShyftApi\ShyftApi\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0"; 
    int port = 7001;

    process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = functionHostPath,
            Arguments = $"start -p {port}",
            WorkingDirectory =  functionAppFolder
        }
    };

    bool success = process.Start();
    Assert.AreEqual(true, success);
    client = new RestClient($"http://localhost:{port}/api");
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //Wait for server to initialize
}

[OneTimeTearDown]
public void OneTimeTearDown()
{
    process.CloseMainWindow();
    process.Dispose();
}

[Test]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("test", Method.GET);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote your answer if you explained what you had to change to get your solution working